# How to install SQLite with Archives extension?

Tags: sqlite

I want to explore the use of SQLite Archive files. I downloaded the amalgamation source code from the downloads page (https://sqlite.org/download.html) and compiled it (`gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl`).

I managed to compile the executable but the Archives option is not there.

Running `./sqlite3 -A` shows the error:

```
./sqlite3: Error: unknown option: -A
```

Trying to run the `.ar` command in commandline shows:

```
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "ar". Enter ".help" for help
```

Running `.help` also does not show the option for `.archive`.

How do I install SQLite with the Archives extension?

Answer (score 1):

Compile from source…

```sh
$ curl -LO https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/sqlite.tar.gz
$ tar xzf sqlite.tar.gz
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../sqlite/configure
$ make
```

You will find the executable command line program (`sqlite3`) in the `build` directory.

Add [compile options](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) by changing the `../sqlite/configure` line to something like…

```sh
$ ../sqlite/configure CFLAGS='-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS=1'
```

View `configure` help for more flags like linking additional libraries…

```sh
$ ../sqlite/configure --help
```

Optionally install the headers (`sqlite3.h`) and libraries (`libsqlite3.a`, `libsqlite3.so`, `libsqlite3.dylib`, etc) by running…

```sh
$ make install
```

Ensure archive support exists…

```sh
$ ./sqlite3 -help
...
OPTIONS include:
  -A ARGS...            run ".archive ARGS" and exit
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile it with `SQLITE_HAVE_ZLIB` defined (And link with `-lz`).

It's easiest using the autoconf or src source distribution, since the configure script tests for a bunch of things including zlib, and compiles the library and shell with a bunch of useful options that you're not using in your manual compilation of the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've downloaded the autoconf source and built the executable. I don't see the `.archive` option still. Not sure what you mean by "compile it with `SQLITE_HAVE_ZLIB` defined" and "link with `-lz`".

I'm not very familiar with compiling with gcc. Can you be more explicit with what I have to do to compile those?